# What's a good way to process RTF-encoded files and convert them to XML?

Tags: xml, regex, perl, rtf

I have never done huge amounts of RTF processing, I always used a library to read or generate one and that was a long time ago. Now I need to get more intimate with the format again, and eventually convert it to XML.

Can you recommend a good path to do it so that I have a lot of control on how RTF chunks are parsed and processed?

Initially, I am thinking Perl plus a few good libraries would be a good choice, but all opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

[RTF Manual](http://rtf2xml.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html)? Seriously though, a quick google turns up all sorts of tools and libraries. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Because it is fun?
Now, that's good for a pet project, not for real world ones with expected results and timelines, indeed... :-P

Comment: Because existing wheels suck? Not saying that necessarily applies here, but in the past i've ended up panning RTF tools for exactly the reason he describes: lack of control over how they're handled.

Comment: then why ask questions here if your response is "rtfm"?  can,t the same response be put on EVERY question on SO?

Comment: Aw come on... how often do you get to point someone at a real manual about RTF - how could I resist?